# Set the boolean property inside all objects with matched name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a nested object that looks like this

```
const test = {
  cat1: {
    id: "c1",
    name: "category1",
    items: [
      {
        itemName: "item1",
        points: 1,
        used: true
      },
      {
        itemName: "item2",
        points: 3,
        used: false
      },
      {
        itemName: "item3",
        points: 5,
        used: true
      }
    ]
  },
  cat2: {
    id: "c2",
    name: "category2",
    items: [
      {
        itemName: "item4",
        points: 7,
        used: true
      },
      {
        itemName: "item5",
        points: 9,
        used: false
      }
    ]
  },
  cat3: {
    id: "c3",
    name: "category3",
    items: [
      {
        itemName: "item6"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

These items are then drawn as checkbox with `used` property as its `checked` value. So whenever I click on `Select All` all the items having `used` property inside the objects should be set to `true`. When `Unselect All`, all the items `used` property should be set to false. I prefer having just one function that basically takes type as `Select All` or `Unselect All` as key and a category `name` so that items under that `name` will be set to either true or false

Here is my try

```
function handleOperation(id, type){
 const output = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(test)
        .map(([k, { items, ...rest }]) => [
          k,
          {
            ...rest,
            items : type === 'Select All' ? 
                       items[k] = items[k].map(item => {
                       item.used = true;
                       return item;
                      }) :
                      items[k] = items[k].map(item => {
                       item.used = false;
                       return item;
                      })
          }
        ]);
    );
  return output;
}

console.log(handleOperation('category1', 'Select All'));
console.log(handleOperation('category2', 'Unselect All'));
```

So when I pass handleOperation('category1', 'Select All')

It should give me, since `category1` items should be updated to true

```
const test = {
  cat1: {
    id: "c1",
    name: "category1",
    items: [
      {
        itemName: "item1",
        points: 1,
        used: true
      },
      {
        itemName: "item2",
        points: 3,
        used: true
      },
      {
        itemName: "item3",
        points: 5,
        used: true
      }
    ]
  },
  cat2: {
    id: "c2",
    name: "category2",
    items: [
      {
        itemName: "item4",
        points: 7,
        used: true
      },
      {
        itemName: "item5",
        points: 9,
        used: false
      }
    ]
  },
  cat3: {
    id: "c3",
    name: "category3",
    items: [
      {
        itemName: "item6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your attempt creates new objects rather than modifying existing objects. Is that important? (For instance, it is with things like React or Vue state...)

Comment: Separately: What specific problem are you having? Does your code not work? In what way?

Comment: Yes this with respect to react

Comment: I'm confused by the code. The data you've shown is an array of objects with `items` properties which are arrays of objects with a `used` property. But your code is looking for `tiles` arrays and assigning a property called `checked`...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry the question was half cooked. I made the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to clone the objects (although you could avoid cloning the ones that don't change; probably an unnecessary optimization), you're on the right track with `Object.fromEntries`, `Object.entries`, and `map`. But you seem to be using the wrong property names, and the code doesn't have to be as complicated as shown.

```
function handleOperation(type) {
    // Get a flag for `type`
    const used = type === "Select All";
    // Build the updated objects
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(test).map(([key, { items, ...rest }]) => [
            key,
            {
                // Copy the rest of this object
                ...rest,
                // Copy its array while mapping the objects
                items: items.map((item) => ({
                    // Copy `items`'s properties
                    ...item,
                    // Set the flag from our `used `variable
                    used,
                })),
            },
        ])
    );
}
```

```js
const test = {
    cat1: {
        id: "c1",
        name: "category1",
        items: [
            {
                itemName: "item1",
                points: 1,
                used: true,
            },
            {
                itemName: "item2",
                points: 3,
                used: false,
            },
            {
                itemName: "item3",
                points: 5,
                used: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    cat2: {
        id: "c2",
        name: "category2",
        items: [
            {
                itemName: "item4",
                points: 7,
                used: true,
            },
            {
                itemName: "item5",
                points: 9,
                used: false,
            },
        ],
    },
    cat3: {
        id: "c3",
        name: "category3",
        items: [
            {
                itemName: "item6",
            },
        ],
    },
};

function handleOperation(type) {
    // Get a flag for `type`
    const used = type === "Select All";
    // Build the updated objects
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(test).map(([key, { items, ...rest }]) => [
            key,
            {
                // Copy the rest of this object
                ...rest,
                // Copy its array while mapping the objects
                items: items.map((item) => ({
                    // Copy `items`'s properties
                    ...item,
                    // Set the flag from our `used `variable
                    used,
                })),
            },
        ])
    );
}

console.log("Select All:");
console.log(handleOperation("Select All"));
console.log("Unselect All:");
console.log(handleOperation("Unselect All"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Thanks a ton. If I want to modify items array with category name being passed. What could be modified? Something like calling handleOperation('category1', 'Select All')), So that only category1 items objects are set to true

One way we could do that is to just avoid calling `map` on `items` if the name of the category doesn't match, using the existing `items` array:

```
function handleOperation(categoryName, type) {
    // Get a flag for `type`
    const used = type === "Select All";
    // Build the updated objects
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(test).map(([key, { name, items, ...rest }]) => [
            key,
            {
                // Copy the name
                name,
                // Copy the rest of this object
                ...rest,
                // If the name doesn't match, reuse `items`; if it does match,
                // copy its array while mapping the objects
                items:
                    name !== categoryName
                        ? items
                        : items.map((item) => ({
                              // Copy `items`'s properties
                              ...item,
                              // Set the flag from our `used `variable
                              used,
                          })),
            },
        ])
    );
}
```

```js
const test = {
    cat1: {
        id: "c1",
        name: "category1",
        items: [
            {
                itemName: "item1",
                points: 1,
                used: true,
            },
            {
                itemName: "item2",
                points: 3,
                used: false,
            },
            {
                itemName: "item3",
                points: 5,
                used: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    cat2: {
        id: "c2",
        name: "category2",
        items: [
            {
                itemName: "item4",
                points: 7,
                used: true,
            },
            {
                itemName: "item5",
                points: 9,
                used: false,
            },
        ],
    },
    cat3: {
        id: "c3",
        name: "category3",
        items: [
            {
                itemName: "item6",
            },
        ],
    },
};

function handleOperation(categoryName, type) {
    // Get a flag for `type`
    const used = type === "Select All";
    // Build the updated objects
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(test).map(([key, { name, items, ...rest }]) => [
            key,
            {
                // Copy the name
                name,
                // Copy the rest of this object
                ...rest,
                // If the name doesn't match, reuse `items`; if it does match,
                // copy its array while mapping the objects
                items:
                    name !== categoryName
                        ? items
                        : items.map((item) => ({
                              // Copy `items`'s properties
                              ...item,
                              // Set the flag from our `used `variable
                              used,
                          })),
            },
        ])
    );
}

console.log("category1 - Select All:");
console.log(handleOperation("category1", "Select All"));
console.log("category1 - Unselect All:");
console.log(handleOperation("category1", "Unselect All"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

But that unnecessarily copies category objects. So let's avoid that as well:

```
function handleOperation(categoryName, type) {
    // Get a flag for `type`
    const used = type === "Select All";
    // Build the updated objects
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(test).map(([key, category]) => {
            if (category.name !== categoryName) {
                return [key, category];
            }
            const { name, items, ...rest } = category;
            return [
                key,
                {
                    // Copy the name
                    name,
                    // Copy the rest of this object
                    ...rest,
                    // Copy its array while mapping the objects
                    items: items.map((item) => ({
                        // Copy `items`'s properties
                        ...item,
                        // Set the flag from our `used `variable
                        used,
                    })),
                },
            ];
        })
    );
}
```

```js
const test = {
    cat1: {
        id: "c1",
        name: "category1",
        items: [
            {
                itemName: "item1",
                points: 1,
                used: true,
            },
            {
                itemName: "item2",
                points: 3,
                used: false,
            },
            {
                itemName: "item3",
                points: 5,
                used: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    cat2: {
        id: "c2",
        name: "category2",
        items: [
            {
                itemName: "item4",
                points: 7,
                used: true,
            },
            {
                itemName: "item5",
                points: 9,
                used: false,
            },
        ],
    },
    cat3: {
        id: "c3",
        name: "category3",
        items: [
            {
                itemName: "item6",
            },
        ],
    },
};

function handleOperation(categoryName, type) {
    // Get a flag for `type`
    const used = type === "Select All";
    // Build the updated objects
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(test).map(([key, category]) => {
            if (category.name !== categoryName) {
                return [key, category];
            }
            const { name, items, ...rest } = category;
            return [
                key,
                {
                    // Copy the name
                    name,
                    // Copy the rest of this object
                    ...rest,
                    // Copy its array while mapping the objects
                    items: items.map((item) => ({
                        // Copy `items`'s properties
                        ...item,
                        // Set the flag from our `used `variable
                        used,
                    })),
                },
            ];
        })
    );
}

console.log("category1 - Select All:");
console.log(handleOperation("category1", "Select All"));
console.log("category1 - Unselect All:");
console.log(handleOperation("category1", "Unselect All"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. If I want to modify items array with category `name` being passed. What could be modified? Something like calling `handleOperation('category1', 'Select All'))`, So that only `category1` items objects are set to true

Comment: @lrr97 - I've updated the answer to help with that. Happy coding!

Comment: You're a savior!

Comment: @lrr97 - LOL Far from it, but thanks. :-)